# Atom Sync two folders on same computer

Tags: netbeans, atom-editor

So I was using NetBeans and when we create a project in NetBeans we have the option to sync the folder where i=I'm working with another one, so what I basically do this: Have one folder called "Dev" and I have on Wamp the folder "www", so I program the files inside the folder "Dev" and when I save (crtl + s) NetBeans auto sync the "Dev" folder with "wamp/www" and I can test in web browser.

But I'm trying to use Atom, it's seems like a really good code editor but I need to have that auto sync when I save the modifications.

Comment: Is your "wamp/www" folder located on the same filesystem as your "Dev" folder? Or do you need to upload your files to an other machine? And if thats the case, which transfer protocol did you use with Netbeans?

Comment: Yes, my wamp/www folder is located on the same system as my Dev @Zahlex